# How to debug javascript in an ASP.net Core 6 - MVC app inside vscode

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code

i am searching for an solution to debug js insinde VSCode. I am running an ASP.net Core MVC app. When I attache the debugger to chrome the breakpoints gets greyed out and dont be hit by the debugger.

Thanks you very much for any suggestion in this case :)

Greetings Arga

Answer (score 0):

VS Code has **built in Javascript debugging**. Its just that You have to configure properly according to your project

You can find full detail here : [**Debugging in VS Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Quick suggestion : I will recommend you to use Visual Studio instead of VSCode for ASP.net Core MVC. It has much options and Nuget packages wich will help u build your MVC app better.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am using a Mac so visual studio for mac don't debug javascript. I have tried visual studio on windows and debugging works out of the box. I am not able to get it work. Not on VSCode and not for Visualstudio for mac. Can you give me some assist in this case? Thanks alot

Comment: @AndreasFrank , Sorry Bro We are the Window Guys :) ... 
But if on MAC this way is not working then the only way left is typing : debugger; in your script and debug into dev tools of ur browser, I find it more convenient, and I mostly debug css & javascript in browser only and after its done, I make changes in my code accordingly.